# Prove $f$ is Lipschitz on $K$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ such that it's partial derivatives are continuous. Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, **a bounded set**. Prove that $f$ is Lipschitz on $K$.

**My work:**
Since $f$'s partial derivatives are continuous that means that $f\in C^1$ (well known fact). We look at $K'$, a compact (could be a closed ball) containing $K$.

$f$ is continuous on $K'$ and therefore, it reaches it's min/max on it. That being said; Let $x,y\in K$:

$$ \frac{\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|}{\|x-y\|} \le  \frac{\left|f(x_{MAX})-f(x_{min})\right|}{\|x-y\|} \le \left|f(x_{MAX})-f(x_{min})\right| = L$$

Hence,

$$ \left|f(y)-f(x)\right| \le L\|x-y\|$$

I'd like to get a proof-verification. I've seen an alternative proof relatively tediuous to mine and I wonder if mine is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: "Well known fact", well, yes, it's the definition of $C^1$.

Comment: Haha.. I meant it's continuously differentiable. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not true** -- for a counterexample, let $d=1$, $K=[0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^2$.

The major problem with your proof is that you don't have any assumptions that will guarantee that $K$ is contained in any compact subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

You also seem to assume that $\|x-y\|\ge 1$, which will not be true in general. So even if you have a $K'$, what you need to bound is $f'$, not $f$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Wait a minute, I forgot to mention $K$ is bounded! (Sorry).

Comment: BUT, indeed, $\|x-y\|$ might be very small. So that's still a problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the case for $d=2$. It extends easily to higher dimensions.

I will assume that $K$ is compact for if $K$ is bounded then it is contained in a compact ball $\subset \mathbb R^{2}$. Note that $f'$ is continuous there, by assumption.

Now, the derivative of $f$ is the linear transformation

$f':\mathbb R^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb R$:

$h=(h_{1},h_{2}) \mapsto h_{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_{1},x_{2}) +h_{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{1},x_{2})=\nabla f(x)\cdot h$

Define $\varphi :\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by

$\varphi (t)=f(x+t(y-x))$. Applying the chain rule and MVT we get a $c\in [0,1]$ and thus a $z=x+c(y-x)$ such that

$\varphi (1)-\varphi (0)=\nabla f(z)\cdot (y-x)$

But $\varphi (1)-\varphi (0)=f(y)-f(x)$ so finally

$f(y)-f(x)=\nabla f(z)\cdot (y-x)$ and the result follows by Cauchy-Schwarz, using the fact that $\vert \nabla f\vert $ is bounded on $K$.